# sql macro parameter

Tags: sql, macros, teradata

This is on Teradata specifically, but in general, is it possible for a macro to accept a list as a parameter?  E.g.,

```
create macro myMacro ( incomingList ) AS
(
  select foo
  from tBar
  where animal in (:incomingList );
);
```

...and then...

```
exec myMacro( ('chicken','pig','cow') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Teradata does not support such kind of macro definition. You must specify a data type associated with the parameter.

You can check out this document: SQL Data Definition Language - Syntax and Examples
and look at the macro part.
http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=091260012